# ReactJS Jest Tesing - fireEvent.click() not triggering a button

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am doing testing first time in my life. I have a stopwatch app, and I want to check with test is secondmeter running. I am doing it by triggering the button and check is 00:00:00 still there.

**Problem is those 00:00:00 are still in the span after triggering a button**. Program working completely fine, not any problem at all. Where is the problem with this triggerin?

I have a button `START` for that:

```
class SecondTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    
    this.state = {
      running: false, // Format to false, so when start a program clock is not running
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    };
  }

 start = () => {
    if (!this.state.running) {
      this.setState({ running: true });
      this.watch = setInterval(() => this.pace(), 10);
    }
  };

{this.state.running === false && (
            <Button className={"start-stop-reset-nappi"} variant="success" size="lg" onClick=
            {this.start}>START</Button>
          )}
```

And I have `span` where time showing (value before starting is 00:00:00, picture of that below).

```
        <span>
          {this.props.formatTime(this.props.currentTimeMin)}:
          {this.props.formatTime(this.props.currentTimeSec)}:
          {this.props.formatTime(this.props.currentTimeMs)}
        </span>
```

Then I have this test:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import SecondTimer from '../components/SecondTimer.jsx';


test('Test - Secondmeter running or not', () => {
  render(<SecondTimer />);

  const start = screen.getByText("START") // Here I'll check is there button (text) like START
  fireEvent.click(start); // Then I "Click" it

  const numbers = screen.getByText(/00:00:00/i) // Check is the 00:00:00 still on screen after triggering the button
  expect(numbers).toBeInTheDocument() 

});
```

[image: Stopwatch app]

Complete component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import SecondTimerNumbers from './SecondTimerNumbers.jsx';
import SecondTimerList from './SecondTimerList.jsx';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


class SecondTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    

    // Start funktio määrittää running arvon -> true, joka kertoo sen, että kello käy. Tallentaa tänne ajan, josta SeconTimerNumber hakee tiedon
    this.state = {
      running: false, // Alustettu falseksi, eli ohjelman avatessa kello ei käy
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    };
  }

  

  // Muuttaa kelloajan numeraaliset luvut stringiksi, sekä lisää yhdet nollat lukuun, jotta luvut ei ns. pompi silmillä.
  formatTime = (val, ...rest) => {
    let value = val.toString();
    if (value.length < 2) {
      value = '0' + value;
    }
    if (rest[0] === 'ms' && value.length < 3) {
      value = '0' + value;
    }
    return value;
  };

  // Start napista painalla käynnistää tämän funktion. Muuttaa state running trueksi, eli kello käy. SetInterval on Reactin oma sekuntikello, ja this.pace 10 määrittelee sadasosasekunnit
  start = () => {
    if (!this.state.running) {
      this.setState({ running: true });
      this.watch = setInterval(() => this.pace(), 10);
    }
  };

  // Stop painikkeesta muuttaa running staten falseksi -> kello pysähtyy, sekä tyhjentää sekuntikellon (pysäyttää).
  stop = () => {
    this.setState({ running: false });
    clearInterval(this.watch);
  };

  // Määrittelee kellon toiminnan
  pace = () => {
    this.setState({ currentTimeMs: this.state.currentTimeMs + 10 }); // Lisää 10ms kerrallaan

    // Kun millisekunteja 1000, lisää yhden sekunnin, sekä muuttaa millisekuntien arvoksi 0 kierroksen jälkeen
    if (this.state.currentTimeMs >= 1000) {
      this.setState({ currentTimeSec: this.state.currentTimeSec + 1 });
      this.setState({ currentTimeMs: 0 });
    }

    // Kun sekunteja on 60, lisää yhden minuutin, sekä muuttaa sekuntien arvoksi 0 kierroksen jälkeen
    if (this.state.currentTimeSec >= 60) {
      this.setState({ currentTimeMin: this.state.currentTimeMin + 1 });
      this.setState({ currentTimeSec: 0 });
    }
  };

  // Määrittää (resetoi) staten allaolevat arvot nollaksi, jolloin sekuntikello voidaan taas aloittaa alusta
  resetTime = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    });
  };



  // UserInterface eli käyttöliittymä renderöityy tässä
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={'main-div'}>
        <div className={'left'}>
          {this.state.running === false && (
            <Button className={"start-stop-reset-nappi"} variant="success" size="lg" onClick={this.start}>START</Button>
          )}
          {this.state.running === true && (
            <Button className={'start-stop-reset-nappi'} variant="warning" size="lg" onClick={this.stop}>PAUSE</Button>
          )}
          <Button className={'start-stop-reset-nappi'} variant="danger" size="lg" onClick={this.resetTime}>RESET</Button>



          <div className={'tulostaulu-main'}>
          <SecondTimerNumbers
            ref="display"
            {...this.state}
            formatTime={this.formatTime}
          />
          </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div className={'right'}>
          <SecondTimerList clickResetTime={this.resetTime}  {...this.state} formatTime={this.formatTime} />
        </div>

      </div>
    );// Yllä oleva ClickResetTime funktio on tämän sivut resetTime funktio.
    // Tällä saan kutsuttua funktiota toisesta componentista, tavallaan "injektoin" funktion tähän componenttiin.
  }
}

export default SecondTimer;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the expected behavior and the observed behavior?

Comment: Looks like the text displaying time `00:00:00` always gets displayed regarding of clicking button or not. Can you share entire code of your component?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Added code of that component. In test there is always 00:00:00, that `fireEvent.click()` dont work? App working normally, this is only test problem. When you click that `START` button clock should start running but it's not.

Comment: So you are expecting the timer to progress, i.e. `00:00:00` should NOT be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what is your problem with your test. I've created a small test based on your current one which works really well.

The idea of the test is pretty simple. As I clicked the button, I expect to see the change in seconds. The key thing is to use `waitFor` api with a specified `timeout` option to make sure testing library resolving your UI change.

Here is the snippet:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { SecondTimer } from "./App";

test("should work", async () => {
  render(<SecondTimer />);

  const start = screen.getByText("START");
  fireEvent.click(start);

  await waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/00:02:00/i), {
    timeout: 2000 // wait 2s 
  });

  const numbers = screen.getByText(/00:02:00/i);

  expect(numbers).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Here is the codesanbox which I've created exclusively for you (The setup to make the test able to run is based on `create-react-app` script):

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-browser-92uks?file=/src/App.test.js

***NOTE***: To run the test, you click a `Tests` tab next to `Browser` on the preview area.

Comment: Thanks! I modified your code little, `timeout: 2000` was not enough. Somehow, this script is slow or something, span got only `00:01:290` when timeout expired. I raised timeout to `3000` then it's waiting one sec longer and get `00:02:00`. It is working now :)) Thanks!